# incorrect coding, php unit, symfony

Tags: encoding, phpunit, symfony4

I have a problem with encoding characters when I'm trying to run test. I'm using Symfony 4 framework with package symfony/phpunit-bridge.

I'm running test by command like below:

```
php bin/phpunit tests/WhovianTest.php
```

The results looks like below:

[image]

As we can see there is a problem with encoding in test's results. I'm using windows 10 operating system and PHPStorm IDE.

How could I solve this problem?

I would be grateful for help.

Answer (score 0):

A standard Windows 10 shell has some issues with the ANSI control characters that are used to display colors (they are quite recognisable with the `?[31;` characters being displayed).  There are some packages to add them, or you can just turn them off.

The phpunit docs suggest:

> On Windows, use [ANSICON](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon) or [ConEmu](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu.)

Alternatively, you can set `colors="false"` in the opening tag of your phpunit.xml, or as a command line parameter: `--colors=never` (try `auto` as well).